# Combine/sort columns with dplyr and/or tidyr

Tags: r, dplyr, igraph, tidyr

EDIT: I've tried a solution below, but as I need to convert the factors to characters and back to factors, I lose some important information.

Having this table, I want it to be sorted from this,

```
From    To  count
A       B     2
A       C     1
C       A     3
B       C     1
```

to this,

```
  From To count
1    A  B     2
2    A  C     4
3    B  C     1
```

So far I see two options, either to do this:

```
df[1:2] <- t(apply(df[1:2], 1, sort))    
aggregate(count ~ From + To, df, sum)
```

which is quite slow as I'm working with 9.000.000 observations. Or simply to convert this into an iGraph network, and merge the edges.

```
g <- graph_from_data_frame(df, directed = TRUE, vertices = nodes)
g <- as.undirected(g, mode = "mutual", edge.attr.comb=list(weight = "sum"))
```

The 2 problems I have are that the first option I've mentioned should actually use dplyr or tidyr, but I couldn't figure out how to do it so far.

The network/igraph option which is quicker than the "t(apply(" option, but I still need to convert the graph back to a data.table for further analysis.

Any idea on how to run the "t(apply(" option with dplyr or tidyr?

Answer (score 3):

We can use `pmin/pmax`.  Should be faster

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
    group_by(From1 = pmin(From, To), To = pmax(From, To)) %>% 
    summarise(count = sum(count)) %>%
    rename(From = From1)
#  From    To count
#  <chr> <chr> <int>
#1     A     B     2
#2     A     C     4
#3     B     C     1
```

Comment: unfortunately I get the following error: `Error: adding class "factor" to an invalid object`.

Comment: @FilipeTeixeira  I considered the `From/To` columns to be `character` class.  So, you can do `df1 %>% mutate_each(funs(as.character), From:to) %>% group_by(...`

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: unfortunately I found another problem with that method. Mutating the variable to characters and back to factors, means that I lose the initial levels. I could create a lookup table but the idea here is actually to have a simpler and quicker code.

Comment: @FilipeTeixeira  Getting the initial levels will be difficult as we are changing the values.  For example in your eexample, you have 'A', 'C', 'B' as levels for the first column, but in the output, 'C' is not there, similarly, in 'To

Answer (score 3):

In base R, we can combine akrun's `pmin` and `pmax` suggestion with `aggregate` using the non-formula interface as follows:

```
aggregate(df$count, list(From=pmin(df$From, df$To), To=pmax(df$From, df$To)), sum)
  From To x
1    A  B 2
2    A  C 4
3    B  C 1
```

Note that this requires that `df$From` and `df$To` are character vectors, not factors.

**timings**
This method is faster than using `apply` as it doesn't involve conversion to matrices. Using the data larger data set below, with 9 million observations, the time to completion using `pmin` and `pmax` with `aggregate` was 14.5 seconds on my computer whereas the OP's method with `apply` took 442.2 seconds or 30 times longer.

**data**

```
df <-
structure(list(From = c("A", "A", "C", "B"), To = c("B", "C", 
"A", "C"), count = c(2L, 1L, 3L, 1L)), .Names = c("From", "To", 
"count"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

**larger sample data**

```
set.seed(1234)
df <- data.frame(From=sample(LETTERS, 9e6, replace=TRUE),
                 To=sample(LETTERS, 9e6, replace=TRUE),
                 count=sample(100, 9e6, replace=TRUE),
                 stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Comment: @Imo Thank you. My problem with the base is the fact that it is slow for my 9.000.000 observations. The solution below works as quickly as it should.

Comment: Please see my update that includes the timings. More often than not, it is that a particular implementation that is slow rather than base R itself.

Comment: @Imo, but again it will cause problems with Factors, which I will need later for data validation.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)
cols_before_merge <- c("From", "To")
out_cols <- c("col_1", "col_2")

df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~From, ~To, ~count,
  "A", "B", 2,
  "A", "C", 1,
  "C", "A", 3,
  "B", "C", 1,
)
```

With the above, I think the  tidyverse approach to creating the unique keys would be:

```
df_out <- df %>%
  dplyr::mutate(
    key = purrr::pmap_chr(
      list(From, To),
      ~ stringr::str_c(stringr::str_sort(c(...)), collapse = "_")
    )
  )
```

Or for a more programmatic approach using [tidy evaluation](https://tidyeval.tidyverse.org/sec-up-to-speed.html):

```
merge_sort <- function(cols_values) {
  purrr::pmap_chr(
    cols_values,
    ~ stringr::str_c(stringr::str_sort(c(...)), collapse = "_")
  )
}

add_key <- function(cols) {
  # column names need to be evaluated using the dataframe as an environment
  cols_quosure <- rlang::enquo(cols)

  # column names should be symbols not strings
  cols_syms <- rlang::syms(cols)

  cols_values <- purrr::map(
    cols_syms,
    ~ rlang::eval_tidy(.x, rlang::quo_get_env(cols_quosure))
  )

  merge_sort(cols_values)
}



# Adding columns for key construction programmatically
df_out <- df %>%
  dplyr::mutate(key = add_key(cols_before_merge))
```

And finally to get a count and make sure the output columns are factors (as akrun points out the factor levels before and after within row sorting could very easily be different).

```
df_out %>%
  dplyr::count(key, name = "count") %>%
  tidyr::separate(key, sep = "_", into = out_cols) %>%
  dplyr::mutate_at(out_cols, as.factor)
```